# How do I calculate a scalar product in a sympy vector?

Tags: math, sympy

Pretty simple question:

```py
from sympy.vector import Vector
v = Vector(0, 2, 1)
print(2*v)
```

Output expected:
Vector(0, 4, 2)

I'm unable to find how to do this, the docs do not talk about scalar product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix understands scalar multiplication but not Vector. So either convert back and forth between Matrix and Vector, file a feature request and wait for a possible enhancement, or write your own `__mul__` and `__rmul__` routine (part of the beauty of Python):

```
>>> v.func(*Matrix(v.args)*2)
Vector(0, 4, 2)
>>> Vector.__rmul__ = Vector.__mul__ = lambda s,o: s.func(*[i*o for i in s.args])
>>> 2*v
Vector(0, 4, 2)
>>> v*2
Vector(0, 4, 2)
```

Comment: Why this functionality is not added to sympy? It is quite intuitive, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think that the `Vector` class is intended to be used this way. None of the vector methods will work on `v`. Probably `Vector(0, 4, 2)` should raise an error. For what you want a column matrix i.e. `Matrix([0, 4, 2])` is appropriate.

Comment: The Point class also allows n-dimensionality: `Point(1,2,3,4)*5 -> Point(5, 10, 15, 20)`. (But `__rmul__` doesn't work, at least in the version on sympy.live.org.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the expected way to work with vectors is to create a coordinate system and use its i, j, k basis:

```
In [32]: from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D                                                                                                   

In [33]: N = CoordSys3D('N')                                                                                                                   

In [34]: v = 2*N.j + N.k                                                                                                                       

In [35]: v                                                                                                                                     
Out[35]: 2*N.j + N.k

In [36]: 2*v                                                                                                                                   
Out[36]: 4*N.j + 2*N.k
```